# NHibernate Linq Query is 3x slower than HQL

Tags: .net, nhibernate, hql, linq-to-nhibernate, nhibernate.search

I have a simple test that runs a query 5000 times. The linq version of the query takes over 3 times the HQL and the cached Linq version is significantly slower than the cached version of HQL

**HQL:**

```
session.CreateQuery(String.Format("from Episode where SeriesId='{0}' and SeasonNumber='{1}' and EpisodeNumber='{2}'", seriesId, seasonNumber, episodeNumber))
               .SetMaxResults(1)
               .SetCacheable(true)
               .UniqueResult<Episode>();
```

**Linq:**

```
session.Query<Episode>()
       .Where(c => c.SeriesId == seriesId && c.SeasonNumber == seasonNumber && c.EpisodeNumber == episodeNumber)
       .Cacheable()
       .FirstOrDefault();
```

Here are the results

```
HQL:   Cached: less than a second   No-Cache: 5 seconds
LINQ:  Cached: 8 seconds            No-Cache: 15 seconds
```

I just want to make sure that I'm experiencing an expected overhead and not something that I'm doing wrong.

if that over head is there and there is not much I could do, can you suggest maybe a middle ground, that would require less strings but provide better performance?

Note:
My cache setting in Fluent Nhibernate
`.Cache(c => c.UseQueryCache().UseSecondLevelCache().UseMinimalPuts().ProviderClass<HashtableCacheProvider>())`

Comment: Is the generated sql statement from the linq test `exactly` the same for all 5000 iterations?

Comment: I don't think its the SQL statement, since the cached version that doesn't even hit the database is 8 seconds compared to less than 1. in both cases the database is only hit once.

Comment: Sorry that should have been my point, Are you sure the database is only hit once for the linq version?

Comment: Yes, I have confirmed this using NHibernate logs, database is only hit once.

Comment: I have noticed the top 1 exists only in the HQL query. The LINQ query probally is getting the first result AFTER the query was made. Can you check that?

Comment: Have you compared the generated SQL statements if they are exactly the same?

Comment: Interesting... Please show the sql statement that Linq generated for you

Comment: Can you use the sql analyze to see what sql is used. You would be able to see if both queries return only 1 record or that the second return a set of records. Then only gets the first in the application.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I guess the problem is the following. This query:

```
session.Query<Episode>()
       .Where(c => c.SeriesId == seriesId && c.SeasonNumber == seasonNumber && c.EpisodeNumber == episodeNumber)
       .Cacheable()
       .FirstOrDefault();
```

loads all episodes from the database, puts them into cache, and then returns the first instance of the collection. When `FirstOrDefault` is called, the query for `Where(c => c.SeriesId == seriesId && c.SeasonNumber == seasonNumber && c.EpisodeNumber == episodeNumber)` is executed and then `FirstOrDefault` is applied on the whole sequence returned.

Something like:

1. `.Where(c => c.SeriesId == seriesId && c.SeasonN...` SQL is executed
2. `.FirstOrDefault()` is evaluated over all elements of collection of 1.

So if you try something like

```
session.Query<Episode>()
       .Where(c => c.SeriesId == seriesId && c.SeasonNumber == seasonNumber && c.EpisodeNumber == episodeNumber)
       .Cacheable()
       .SetMaxResults(1)
       .UniqueResult();
```

it should behave the same like your HQL query.